# Exterior tensor of derived categories of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be Noetherian perfect derived stacks over $S$ a regular perfect derived stack.  Consider the exterior tensor functor
$$\text{DCoh}(X) \otimes_{\text{DCoh}(S)} \text{DCoh}(Y) \rightarrow \text{DCoh}(X \times_S Y)$$
This map is, in general, fully faithful.  When is it also essentially surjective (and thus an equivalence)?  There are some affirmative answers: in the appendix to Preygel's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5834), it's shown that this is an equivalence when:

- $X$ and $Y$ are almost finitely-presented Deligne-Mumford stacks with finite diagonal, and $S = \text{Spec}(k)$ a perfect field
- $Y \rightarrow S$ is a smooth relative scheme, and $X$ is an excellent derived stack over $S$
- this is not in the paper, but it is an easy case: when $X$ and $Y$ are both smooth over $S$, then then $\text{DCoh} = \text{Perf}$ and the result follows from work by Ben-Zvi/Francis/Nadler (for example, if $X = Y = BG$ and $G$ is affine, this says that every $G \times G$-representation is a sum of exterior tensors of $G$-representations).

I'm particularly interested in the case when we don't require either $X$ or $Y$ to be Deligne-Mumford over $S$, but more generally, allow them to be Artin stacks, and also when $X = Y$.  Even more concretely, say $X = Y = Z/G$ where $Z$ is not smooth, and $S = \text{Spec}(k)$ is a characteristic zero algebraically closed.  Are there known counterexamples?

Comment: I guess that in your third $\bullet$ you refer to Theorem 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0157.

Comment: @HeinrichD Yes, that's the one.  The referenced theorems in the Preygel paper are B.3.2. and B.4.1

Comment: This sounds strange --- I would say that one should allow taking direct summands if one wants to obtain any object on the product in terms of decomposable objects.

Comment: I think you'll find answers to your questions here:  http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/Finiteness.pdf for example Cor. 4.2.3, Prop. 3.5.1 etc

Comment: @DanielPomerleano Thanks, that seems to be what I need.  Not sure how I missed it... I was just looking at this the other day.

Comment: If you're interested in functor categories rather than tensor products, you'll find more in https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7164 (here it makes a big difference here if you're asking about small categories DCoh or big categories IndCoh -- the former are not dualizable so the tensor product and functor category calculations are distinct).

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for the comment; you are right.  I was confused about the tensor product.  For posterity: the way it's usually defined is to take the tensor product of the "big" ind-completion of the above categories and then take the compact objects of the resulting presentable category.  In particular, the compact objects of the ind-completion of a stable $\infty$-category is its idempotent completion (one can take direct summands via an infinite colimit).  Reference: Higher Topos Theory 4.4.5.16, 5.4.2.4